# How to execute those 2 code snippets asynchronously/parallell

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ccxt

I am beginner at javascript so please bear with me. I wonder how to put async() event in the right way.
I have 2 code snippets that I want to execute asynchronously and not synchronously. The code snippets use a library that do HTTP requests so that is out of my control.

So I like the 2 code snippets to execute in parallell somehow. What I have are those 2 code snippets and I also think I understand that I only want to declare the first 2 lines once as those lines takes time:

```
'use strict';
 const ccxt = require ('ccxt');
```

The 2 code snippets are the below

**Code snippet1:**

```js
'use strict';
const ccxt = require ('ccxt');

(async () => {
            try{
       const exchange = new ccxt.one({ enableRateLimit: true })
       const tickers = await exchange.fetchTickers()
       const obj = { tickers }
       const fs = require('fs');
       fs.writeFile("/myproject/file1.txt", JSON.stringify(obj), function(err) { });
       }catch{}
}) ()
```

**Code snippet2:**

```js
'use strict';
const ccxt = require ('ccxt');

(async () => {
            try{
       const exchange = new ccxt.two({ enableRateLimit: true })
       const tickers = await exchange.fetchTickers()
       const obj = { tickers }
       const fs = require('fs');
       fs.writeFile("/myproject/file2.txt", JSON.stringify(obj), function(err) { });
       }catch{}
}) ()
```

Comment: Might you simply paste the second IIFE below the first one?

Comment: Okay, you mean that I could just add the other "async" event after the other. Should that work and is that correct to do it that way?

Comment: It's one option. Try it, see if it achieves what you're looking for

Comment: Yes okay, I will try it and post the code if it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code and it actually did it in parallell. It executed very fast.

If you have any idéas of code to add to make it even more efficient I would be very happy to hear how to do that. (For example open up more ports or any other bottlenecks?)

```js
'use strict';
const ccxt = require ('ccxt');

(async () => {
            try{
       const exchange = new ccxt.one({ enableRateLimit: true })
       const tickers = await exchange.fetchTickers()
       const obj = { tickers }
       const fs = require('fs');
       fs.writeFile("/myproject/file1.txt", JSON.stringify(obj), function(err) { });
       }catch{}
}) ();

(async () => {
            try{
       const exchange = new ccxt.two({ enableRateLimit: true })
       const tickers = await exchange.fetchTickers()
       const obj = { tickers }
       const fs = require('fs');
       fs.writeFile("/myproject/file2.txt", JSON.stringify(obj), function(err) { });
       }catch{}
}) ();
```

Comment: You can also place `const fs = require('fs');` out of the functions, alongside with `const ccxt = require ('ccxt');`.

Comment: Yes that was a good idéa to make it global. Thanks for the idéa!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Promise.all`:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

```js
'use strict';

const ccxt = require ('ccxt')
const fs   = require('fs')

async function work (exchangeId) {
    try {
        const exchange = new ccxt[exchangeId] ({ enableRateLimit: true })
        const tickers = await exchange.fetchTickers ()
        const obj = { tickers }
        const filename = exchangeId + '.txt'
        fs.writeFileSync (filename, JSON.stringify (obj))
        console.log ('saved', filename)
    } catch {
    }
}

(async () => {
    const exchangeIds = [ 'bittrex', 'bitfinex' ]
    await Promise.all (exchangeIds.map (exchangeId => work (exchangeId)))
}) ()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you want to happen but your code will not catch all errors as written. I know you seemed to be ignoring all errors but just in case, ...

If you're going to use async/await then you should go all in. That means you should use [`fs.promises.readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readfile_path_options) not `fs.readFile`. Either that or you should wrap `fs.readFile` in a promise either manually or using `util.promisify`.

So the code becomes

```
'use strict';
const ccxt = require ('ccxt');

const thing1 = (async () => {
   try{
       const exchange = new ccxt.one({ enableRateLimit: true })
       const tickers = await exchange.fetchTickers()
       const obj = { tickers }
       const fs = require('fs');
       await fs.promises.writeFile("/myproject/file1.txt", JSON.stringify(obj));
   } catch {
      // catch error here
   }
}) ();

const thing2 = (async () => {
    try{
       const exchange = new ccxt.two({ enableRateLimit: true })
       const tickers = await exchange.fetchTickers()
       const obj = { tickers }
       const fs = require('fs');
       await fs.promises.writeFile("/myproject/file2.txt", JSON.stringify(obj));
    } catch {
      // catch error here
    }
}) ();
```

If wanted to do both to wait for both things then you could use `Promise.all` by passing in an array that contain each of the promises returned by both async functions.

```
'use strict';
const ccxt = require ('ccxt');

const thing1 = (async () => {
   try{
       const exchange = new ccxt.one({ enableRateLimit: true })
       const tickers = await exchange.fetchTickers()
       const obj = { tickers }
       const fs = require('fs');
       await fs.promises.writeFile("/myproject/file1.txt", JSON.stringify(obj));
   } catch {
      // catch error here
   }
}) ();

const thing2 = (async () => {
    try{
       const exchange = new ccxt.two({ enableRateLimit: true })
       const tickers = await exchange.fetchTickers()
       const obj = { tickers }
       const fs = require('fs');
       await fs.promises.writeFile("/myproject/file2.txt", JSON.stringify(obj));
    } catch {
      // catch error here
    }
}) ();

(async() => {
  await Promise.all([thing1, thing2]);

  // do something after thing1 and thing2
}) ();
```

And of course at given the 2 functions are the same except for the filename then

```
'use strict';
const ccxt = require ('ccxt');

async function fetchTickersAndWrite({method, filename}) {
   try{
       const exchange = new ccxt[method]({ enableRateLimit: true })
       const tickers = await exchange.fetchTickers()
       const obj = { tickers }
       const fs = require('fs');
       await fs.promises.writeFile(filename, JSON.stringify(obj));
   } catch {
      // catch error here
   }
}

(async() => {
  await Promise.all([
    { method: 'one', filename: `/myproject/file1.txt` },
    { method: 'two', filename: `/myproject/file2.txt` },
  ].map(fetchTickersAndWrite));

  // do something
}) ();
```